# Remove back button if platform is Android

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, back-button

i have a problem in my app. (i'm using Ionic v1) 
I want to hide the back button if the platform is Android, but if is iOS i want to show it.

I have the following code:

```
.config(function($ionicConfigProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
// if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/login');

if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
    $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.style("tabs-icon-top tabs-striped");
    $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position("top");
    $ionicConfigProvider.navBar.alignTitle("center");
}
else if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
    $ionicConfigProvider.backButton.text('').icon('ion-arrow-left-c');
    $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.style("tabs-icon-top tabs-striped");
    $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position("top");
    $ionicConfigProvider.navBar.alignTitle("center");
}
```

});

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside $ionicPlatform.ready method:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
 if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
     $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.style("tabs-icon-top tabs-striped");
     $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position("top");
     $ionicConfigProvider.navBar.alignTitle("center");
 }
 else if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
     $ionicConfigProvider.backButton.text('').icon('ion-arrow-left-c');
     $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.style("tabs-icon-top tabs-striped");
     $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position("top");
     $ionicConfigProvider.navBar.alignTitle("center");
 }
});
```